# novel about man awakening in the future on a planet with intelligent forest and feline-humanoid species

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this story/novel in the 1970s.  My recollections are :
A man wakes up thousands of years in the future, on a planet which turns out to be Earth (maybe).  The man had been somehow petrified, and awakened, due to electricity or lightening.
The planet has beings which are feline-like and also canine-like (and I think the two species were in conflict with each other).
The man has a romantic situation with one of the cat-ladies.
There is some influence of a giant intelligent tree which governs and permeates the planet.
The man was considered a deity because he awoke from stone (not sure about that part though).
Thanks for any help finding if this was a real book or my imagination.

Comment: As others have mentioned, it is Philip José Farmers "The Stone God Awakens", which was also the answer to a past, similar question.

Comment: I agree; the book I was looking for is The Stone God Awakens. Question answered. Thank you.